# Entity framework nested projections are slow

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, refactoring

I'm running a query to fetch a users profile. The query get the users details, as well as all the reviews they have posted, as well as the comments in the reviews.

It may well be a case of I'm trying to get back too much, but as the api is getting called from mobile, I'd rather get as much as I can in one network call rather than making multiple network calls.

At the moment this is generating some really long sql, and takes around 25 seconds!

Any tips on how to improve it, or whether projections are even right way to do it

```
public UserVM GetUserInfo(string userId, string currentUserId)
{
    var results =
         from u in context.AspNetUsers
         where u.Id == userId
         select new UserVM
         {
             Name = u.UserName, Id = u.Id, ProfilePic = u.ProfilePicUrl, FollowerCount = u.Followers.Count, FollowingCount = u.Following.Count,
             MemberSince = u.RegisteredDate,
             RatingsCount = u.Ratings.Count(x => x.IsDeleted!=true),
             FollowedByCurrentUser = currentUserId != null && u.Followers.Any(x => x.FollowedByUserId == currentUserId && x.UserId == userId),
             reviews = 
               from r in u.Ratings
               where r.IsDeleted != true
               && r.IsDraft != true

               select new RatingVM()
               {
                   ratingId = r.Id,
                   author_name = r.User.UserName,
                   userId = r.UserId,
                   profile_photo_url = r.User.ProfilePicUrl,
                   rating = r.RatingValue,
                   text = r.RatingComment,
                   created = r.Created,
                   likeCount = r.RatingLikes.Count(x => x.IsLiked && x.RatingId == r.Id),
                   likedByCurrentUser = currentUserId != null && r.RatingLikes.Any(x => x.IsLiked && x.RatingId == r.Id && x.UserId == currentUserId),
                   photos = from ri in r.RatingImages
                            select new PhotoVM { Id = ri.Id, width = 0, height = 0, photo_reference = ri.PhotoUrl, isMember = true, googlePlaceId = r.Place.GooglePlaceId, placeName = r.Place.Name },
                   comments = from c in r.Comments
                              where c.IsDeleted != true 
                              select new CommentVM { commentId = c.Id, Created = c.Created, CommentText = c.CommentText, RatingId = r.Id , UserName = c.User.UserName, ProfilePicUrl = c.User.ProfilePicUrl, userId = c.UserId }
               }
         };

    return results.FirstOrDefault();
}



SELECT 
[Project17].[C1] AS [C1], 
[Project17].[UserName] AS [UserName], 
[Project17].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Project17].[ProfilePicUrl] AS [ProfilePicUrl], 
[Project17].[C32] AS [C2], 
[Project17].[C33] AS [C3], 
[Project17].[RegisteredDate] AS [RegisteredDate], 
[Project17].[C34] AS [C4], 
[Project17].[C2] AS [C5], 
[Project17].[C31] AS [C6], 
[Project17].[C4] AS [C7], 
[Project17].[C5] AS [C8], 
[Project17].[C6] AS [C9], 
[Project17].[C7] AS [C10], 
[Project17].[C8] AS [C11], 
[Project17].[C9] AS [C12], 
[Project17].[C10] AS [C13], 
[Project17].[C11] AS [C14], 
[Project17].[C12] AS [C15], 
[Project17].[C13] AS [C16], 
[Project17].[C14] AS [C17], 
[Project17].[C3] AS [C18], 
[Project17].[C15] AS [C19], 
[Project17].[C16] AS [C20], 
[Project17].[C17] AS [C21], 
[Project17].[C18] AS [C22], 
[Project17].[C19] AS [C23], 
[Project17].[C20] AS [C24], 
[Project17].[C21] AS [C25], 
[Project17].[C22] AS [C26], 
[Project17].[C23] AS [C27], 
[Project17].[C24] AS [C28], 
[Project17].[C25] AS [C29], 
[Project17].[C26] AS [C30], 
[Project17].[C27] AS [C31], 
[Project17].[C28] AS [C32], 
[Project17].[C29] AS [C33], 
[Project17].[C30] AS [C34]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Limit1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Limit1].[UserName] AS [UserName], 
    [Limit1].[ProfilePicUrl] AS [ProfilePicUrl], 
    [Limit1].[RegisteredDate] AS [RegisteredDate], 
    [Limit1].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [Limit1].[C2] AS [C2], 
    [UnionAll1].[C1] AS [C3], 
    [UnionAll1].[Id] AS [C4], 
    [UnionAll1].[Id1] AS [C5], 
    [UnionAll1].[C2] AS [C6], 
    [UnionAll1].[C3] AS [C7], 
    [UnionAll1].[UserId] AS [C8], 
    [UnionAll1].[C4] AS [C9], 
    [UnionAll1].[RatingValue] AS [C10], 
    [UnionAll1].[RatingComment] AS [C11], 
    [UnionAll1].[Created] AS [C12], 
    [UnionAll1].[C5] AS [C13], 
    [UnionAll1].[C6] AS [C14], 
    [UnionAll1].[Id2] AS [C15], 
    [UnionAll1].[Id3] AS [C16], 
    [UnionAll1].[C7] AS [C17], 
    [UnionAll1].[C8] AS [C18], 
    [UnionAll1].[PhotoUrl] AS [C19], 
    [UnionAll1].[C9] AS [C20], 
    [UnionAll1].[GooglePlaceId] AS [C21], 
    [UnionAll1].[Name] AS [C22], 
    [UnionAll1].[C10] AS [C23], 
    [UnionAll1].[C11] AS [C24], 
    [UnionAll1].[C12] AS [C25], 
    [UnionAll1].[C13] AS [C26], 
    [UnionAll1].[C14] AS [C27], 
    [UnionAll1].[C15] AS [C28], 
    [UnionAll1].[C16] AS [C29], 
    [UnionAll1].[C17] AS [C30], 
    CASE WHEN ([UnionAll1].[Id] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C31], 
    [Limit1].[C3] AS [C32], 
    [Limit1].[C4] AS [C33], 
    [Limit1].[C5] AS [C34]
    FROM   (SELECT TOP (1) 
        @p__linq__4 AS [p__linq__4], 
        @p__linq__5 AS [p__linq__5], 
        [Project3].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Project3].[UserName] AS [UserName], 
        [Project3].[ProfilePicUrl] AS [ProfilePicUrl], 
        [Project3].[RegisteredDate] AS [RegisteredDate], 
        1 AS [C1], 
        CASE WHEN ((@p__linq__1 IS NOT NULL) AND ( EXISTS (SELECT 
            1 AS [C1]
            FROM [dbo].[Followers] AS [Extent5]
            WHERE ([Project3].[Id] = [Extent5].[UserId]) AND ([Extent5].[FollowedByUserId] = @p__linq__2) AND ([Extent5].[UserId] = @p__linq__3)
        ))) THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END AS [C2], 
        [Project3].[C1] AS [C3], 
        [Project3].[C2] AS [C4], 
        [Project3].[C3] AS [C5]
        FROM ( SELECT 
            [Project2].[Id] AS [Id], 
            [Project2].[UserName] AS [UserName], 
            [Project2].[ProfilePicUrl] AS [ProfilePicUrl], 
            [Project2].[RegisteredDate] AS [RegisteredDate], 
            [Project2].[C1] AS [C1], 
            [Project2].[C2] AS [C2], 
            (SELECT 
                COUNT(1) AS [A1]
                FROM [dbo].[Ratings] AS [Extent4]
                WHERE ([Project2].[Id] = [Extent4].[UserId]) AND (1 <> [Extent4].[IsDeleted])) AS [C3]
            FROM ( SELECT 
                [Project1].[Id] AS [Id], 
                [Project1].[UserName] AS [UserName], 
                [Project1].[ProfilePicUrl] AS [ProfilePicUrl], 
                [Project1].[RegisteredDate] AS [RegisteredDate], 
                [Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
                (SELECT 
                    COUNT(1) AS [A1]
                    FROM [dbo].[Followers] AS [Extent3]
                    WHERE [Project1].[Id] = [Extent3].[FollowedByUserId]) AS [C2]
                FROM ( SELECT 
                    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
                    [Extent1].[UserName] AS [UserName], 
                    [Extent1].[ProfilePicUrl] AS [ProfilePicUrl], 
                    [Extent1].[RegisteredDate] AS [RegisteredDate], 
                    (SELECT 
                        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
                        FROM [dbo].[Followers] AS [Extent2]
                        WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[UserId]) AS [C1]
                    FROM [dbo].[AspNetUsers] AS [Extent1]
                    WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = @p__linq__0
                )  AS [Project1]
            )  AS [Project2]
        )  AS [Project3] ) AS [Limit1]
    OUTER APPLY  (SELECT 
        CASE WHEN ([Filter10].[Id1] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C1], 
        [Project9].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Project9].[Id] AS [Id1], 
        [Project9].[C1] AS [C2], 
        [Project9].[C2] AS [C3], 
        [Project9].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
        [Project9].[C3] AS [C4], 
        [Project9].[RatingValue] AS [RatingValue], 
        [Project9].[RatingComment] AS [RatingComment], 
        [Project9].[Created] AS [Created], 
        [Project9].[C5] AS [C5], 
        [Project9].[C4] AS [C6], 
        [Filter10].[Id1] AS [Id2], 
        [Filter10].[Id1] AS [Id3], 
        CASE WHEN ([Filter10].[Id1] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 0 END AS [C7], 
        CASE WHEN ([Filter10].[Id1] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 0 END AS [C8], 
        [Filter10].[PhotoUrl] AS [PhotoUrl], 
        CASE WHEN ([Filter10].[Id1] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS bit) ELSE cast(1 as bit) END AS [C9], 
        [Filter10].[GooglePlaceId] AS [GooglePlaceId], 
        [Filter10].[Name] AS [Name], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C10], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C11], 
        CAST(NULL AS datetime2) AS [C12], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C13], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C14], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C15], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C16], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C17]
        FROM   (SELECT 
            [Project7].[Id] AS [Id], 
            [Project7].[RatingValue] AS [RatingValue], 
            [Project7].[RatingComment] AS [RatingComment], 
            [Project7].[Created] AS [Created], 
            [Project7].[PlaceId] AS [PlaceId], 
            [Project7].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
            [Limit1].[UserName] AS [C1], 
            N'' AS [C2], 
            [Limit1].[ProfilePicUrl] AS [C3], 
            CASE WHEN ((@p__linq__4 IS NOT NULL) AND ( EXISTS (SELECT 
                1 AS [C1]
                FROM [dbo].[RatingLikes] AS [Extent8]
                WHERE ([Project7].[Id] = [Extent8].[RatingId]) AND ([Extent8].[IsLiked] = 1) AND ([Extent8].[RatingId] = [Project7].[Id]) AND ([Extent8].[UserId] = @p__linq__5)
            ))) THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END AS [C4], 
            [Project7].[C1] AS [C5]
            FROM ( SELECT 
                [Project6].[Id] AS [Id], 
                [Project6].[RatingValue] AS [RatingValue], 
                [Project6].[RatingComment] AS [RatingComment], 
                [Project6].[Created] AS [Created], 
                [Project6].[PlaceId] AS [PlaceId], 
                [Project6].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
                (SELECT 
                    COUNT(1) AS [A1]
                    FROM [dbo].[RatingLikes] AS [Extent7]
                    WHERE ([Project6].[Id] = [Extent7].[RatingId]) AND ([Extent7].[IsLiked] = 1) AND ([Extent7].[RatingId] = [Project6].[Id])) AS [C1]
                FROM ( SELECT 
                    [Extent6].[Id] AS [Id], 
                    [Extent6].[RatingValue] AS [RatingValue], 
                    [Extent6].[RatingComment] AS [RatingComment], 
                    [Extent6].[Created] AS [Created], 
                    [Extent6].[PlaceId] AS [PlaceId], 
                    [Extent6].[UserId] AS [UserId]
                    FROM [dbo].[Ratings] AS [Extent6]
                    WHERE ([Limit1].[Id] = [Extent6].[UserId]) AND (1 <> [Extent6].[IsDeleted]) AND (1 <> [Extent6].[IsDraft])
                )  AS [Project6]
            )  AS [Project7] ) AS [Project9]
        OUTER APPLY  (SELECT [Extent9].[Id] AS [Id1], [Extent9].[PhotoUrl] AS [PhotoUrl], [Project10].[Name] AS [Name], [Project10].[GooglePlaceId] AS [GooglePlaceId]
            FROM  [dbo].[RatingImages] AS [Extent9]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT 
                [Extent10].[Id] AS [Id], 
                [Extent10].[Name] AS [Name], 
                [Extent10].[GooglePlaceId] AS [GooglePlaceId]
                FROM [dbo].[Places] AS [Extent10]
                WHERE [Project9].[PlaceId] = [Extent10].[Id] ) AS [Project10] ON 1 = 1
            WHERE [Project9].[Id] = [Extent9].[RatingId] ) AS [Filter10]
    UNION ALL
        SELECT 
        2 AS [C1], 
        [Project15].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Project15].[Id] AS [Id1], 
        [Project15].[C1] AS [C2], 
        [Project15].[C2] AS [C3], 
        [Project15].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
        [Project15].[C3] AS [C4], 
        [Project15].[RatingValue] AS [RatingValue], 
        [Project15].[RatingComment] AS [RatingComment], 
        [Project15].[Created] AS [Created], 
        [Project15].[C5] AS [C5], 
        [Project15].[C4] AS [C6], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C7], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C8], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C9], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C10], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C11], 
        CAST(NULL AS bit) AS [C12], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C13], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C14], 
        [Join2].[Id2] AS [Id2], 
        [Join2].[Id2] AS [Id3], 
        [Join2].[Created] AS [Created1], 
        [Join2].[CommentText] AS [CommentText], 
        [Project15].[Id] AS [Id4], 
        [Join2].[UserName] AS [UserName], 
        [Join2].[ProfilePicUrl] AS [ProfilePicUrl], 
        [Join2].[UserId] AS [UserId1]
        FROM   (SELECT 
            [Project13].[Id] AS [Id], 
            [Project13].[RatingValue] AS [RatingValue], 
            [Project13].[RatingComment] AS [RatingComment], 
            [Project13].[Created] AS [Created], 
            [Project13].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
            [Limit1].[UserName] AS [C1], 
            N'' AS [C2], 
            [Limit1].[ProfilePicUrl] AS [C3], 
            CASE WHEN ((@p__linq__4 IS NOT NULL) AND ( EXISTS (SELECT 
                1 AS [C1]
                FROM [dbo].[RatingLikes] AS [Extent13]
                WHERE ([Project13].[Id] = [Extent13].[RatingId]) AND ([Extent13].[IsLiked] = 1) AND ([Extent13].[RatingId] = [Project13].[Id]) AND ([Extent13].[UserId] = @p__linq__5)
            ))) THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END AS [C4], 
            [Project13].[C1] AS [C5]
            FROM ( SELECT 
                [Project12].[Id] AS [Id], 
                [Project12].[RatingValue] AS [RatingValue], 
                [Project12].[RatingComment] AS [RatingComment], 
                [Project12].[Created] AS [Created], 
                [Project12].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
                (SELECT 
                    COUNT(1) AS [A1]
                    FROM [dbo].[RatingLikes] AS [Extent12]
                    WHERE ([Project12].[Id] = [Extent12].[RatingId]) AND ([Extent12].[IsLiked] = 1) AND ([Extent12].[RatingId] = [Project12].[Id])) AS [C1]
                FROM ( SELECT 
                    [Extent11].[Id] AS [Id], 
                    [Extent11].[RatingValue] AS [RatingValue], 
                    [Extent11].[RatingComment] AS [RatingComment], 
                    [Extent11].[Created] AS [Created], 
                    [Extent11].[UserId] AS [UserId]
                    FROM [dbo].[Ratings] AS [Extent11]
                    WHERE ([Limit1].[Id] = [Extent11].[UserId]) AND (1 <> [Extent11].[IsDeleted]) AND (1 <> [Extent11].[IsDraft])
                )  AS [Project12]
            )  AS [Project13] ) AS [Project15]
        INNER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent14].[Id] AS [Id2], [Extent14].[CommentText] AS [CommentText], [Extent14].[Created] AS [Created], [Extent14].[RatingId] AS [RatingId], [Extent14].[IsDeleted] AS [IsDeleted], [Extent14].[UserId] AS [UserId], [Extent15].[UserName] AS [UserName], [Extent15].[ProfilePicUrl] AS [ProfilePicUrl]
            FROM  [dbo].[Comments] AS [Extent14]
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[AspNetUsers] AS [Extent15] ON [Extent14].[UserId] = [Extent15].[Id] ) AS [Join2] ON ([Project15].[Id] = [Join2].[RatingId]) AND (1 <> [Join2].[IsDeleted])) AS [UnionAll1]
)  AS [Project17]
ORDER BY [Project17].[Id] ASC, [Project17].[C31] ASC, [Project17].[C5] ASC, [Project17].[C3] ASC
```

Comment: What EF version are you on? Can we see the generated SQL? Because the query looks ok, just eventually replacing `r.User` with `u`.

Comment: @IvanStoev. I've tried commenting out parts, and it seems like the last couple of line  (setting photos and comments) is what is driving the time to execute up. - any suggestions?

Comment: Apparently they are detail subqueries inside detail subquery, but with appropriate indexes (which EF normally creates on FK columns) it's not a problem usually, and I don't see how they can be improved. Also the root query is for single user, so the data should not be so much. You could eventually split it on two parts (execute 2 db queries), but before doing that, it would be nice the see the currently generated SQL.

Comment: @IvanStoev Generated sql now included, as you  can see it's generating a lot of code.

Comment: It's indeed big. For some reason, `[dbo].[Ratings]` is included 4 times and [`dbo].[AspNetUser]` 2 times which is strange. Have you tried replacing all `r.User` occurrences with `u` as suggested?

Comment: yes, replaced r.User with u now, oddly its usually slow the first time, the subsequent calls are quick...In any case, is there a better way I should be doing this?

Comment: I think you are doing it just fine, so the performance issue is from EF. You can try splitting the query on parts, but it will require additional coding and will basically kill the benefits of using LINQ and EF.

Comment: Hello. Without knowing your table structure i can see that you are doing to many select queries but possibly you could remove a lot of them if you were going with join statements. If you have a DBA i would recommend to sit down with him and create the sql query and then translate it back to linq. As for the Subsequent calls they are quick because the linq is translated to sql and it can directly run it. (The warm up phase is to create the sql query from the linq and then it uses directly the sql query for any later use) Also you could create it as a view and then use the view in the linq

Comment: `u.Followers.Count`, `u.Following.Count`, without parentheses, is that correct?

Comment: @Gert Arnold if the Follower and the Following are of type `ICollection<T>` yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF6's loading strategy of using one big SQL query per LINQ query is not optimal for loading complex object graphs.  There are several other ways to get your graph loaded.

For instance you could load the root AspNetUser entity, and then traverse the Navigation Properties to build your graph.  EF would Lazy Load as needed.  And once an entity is cached in the context, subsequent navigations would not cause additional queries.

In fact if you pre-fetch some or all of the related entities, EF will "stitch" or "fix-up" your navigation properties.

So as an optimization, you can write queries that fetch into the context cache the entities that you will need using a few simple and cheap queries.

something like

```
 var user = context.AspNetUsers.Where(u => u.Id == userId).Single();
 var followers = context.Followers.Where(f => f.UserId == userId).ToList();
 var ratings = context.Ratings.Where(f => f.UserId == userId).ToList();
 var ratingIds = ratings.Select(r => r.Id).ToList();
 var ratingLikes = context.RatingLikes.Where(x => ratingIds.Contains(x.RatingId) && x.IsLiked ).ToList();
 var ratingPhotos = context.RatingPhotos.Where(x => ratingIds.Contains(x.RatingId)).ToList();
```

Then build your results from the loaded AspNetUser,  eg

```
  var u = user;
  var results =
              select new UserVM
                    {
                         Name = u.UserName,
                         Id = u.Id,
                         ProfilePic = u.ProfilePicUrl,
                         FollowerCount = u.Followers.Count, . . .
```

Comment: I tried the loading the user with a bunch of includes (then mapping it into my vm): var user = AspNetUsers
.Include(x=>x.Followers)
.Include(x=>x.Following)
.Include(x=>x.Ratings)
.Include("Ratings.Place")
.Include("Ratings.RatingImages")
.Include("Ratings.Comments")
.Include("Ratings.Comments.User")
.Include("Ratings.RatingLikes")
.Single (a => a.Id == userId);... does this seem like a sensible way too?

Comment: No not sensible. Includes will load every column from the included tables.  Projection is better.  Have you run your query through the Database engine tuning adviser?

Comment: Includes() might generate a simpler query, but it will still be one big query, and as @Phil points out, what you gain in query simplicity you might loose in result size.  You might fetch one branch of related entities with Include() when you fetch the User, but not everything.