# Query Performance on Many To Many With EF6

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

We're running into a performance issue with a query that utilizes a few M:M relationships with a single table.

**Tables:**

[image: Schema]

Currently, EF generates a MONSTROUS query that uses UNION ALL to the Contact table 3 times. [Pastebin of SQL](https://pastebin.com/7MmaVRrx)  Once for each join.  Our projection is like so

```
var contacts = query.Select(contact => new Contact
            {
                Brands = contact.Brands.Select(b => new Brand
                {
                    Id = b.Id,
                    Name = b.Name,
                    Aliases = b.Aliases.Select(a => a.Value).ToList()
                }).ToList(),
                Categories = contact.Categories.Select(category => new Category
                {
                    Id = category.Id
                }).ToList(),
                ContactTypes = contact.ContactTypes.Select(ct => new ContactType
                {
                    Id = ct.Id
                }).ToList(),
                Disabled = contact.Disabled,
                Email = contact.Email,
                Fax = contact.Fax,
                Id = contact.Id,
                Latitude = contact.Coordinates != null ? contact.Coordinates.Latitude : 0,
                Longitude = contact.Coordinates != null ? contact.Coordinates.Longitude : 0,
                Distance = searchLocation != null && contact.Coordinates != null ? searchLocation.Distance(contact.Coordinates) * conversionFactor : 0,
                PostalCode = contact.PostalCode,
                PhoneSupport = contact.PhoneSupport,
                PhoneSales = contact.PhoneSales,
                PhoneAfterHoursSupport = contact.PhoneAfterHoursSupport,
                Phone = contact.Phone,
                Preferred = contact.Preferred,
                ShopOnlineImageUrl = contact.ShopOnlineImageUrl,
                ContactTranslations = contact.NameContent.TranslatedContents.Where(tc => tc.IsoLanguageCode == searchModel.IsoLanguageCode ||
                                                                                         tc.IsoLanguageCode == SearchContactsHelpers.ISO_LANGUAGE_CODE_ENGLISH)
                                                                            .Select(tc => new ContactTranslationImpl
                                                                            {
                                                                                Name = tc.Value,
                                                                                IsoLanguageCode = tc.IsoLanguageCode,
                                                                                NameId = tc.MasterContentId
                                                                            }).ToList(),
                AdditionalInformationContentId = contact.AdditionalInformationContentId,
                AddressLine1ContentId = contact.AddressLine1ContentId,
                AddressLine2ContentId = contact.AddressLine2ContentId,
                CityContentId = contact.CityContentId,
                StateOrProvinceContentId = contact.StateOrProvinceContentId,
                CountryContentId = contact.Country.NameContentId,
                HoursOfOperationContentId = contact.HoursOfOperationContentId,
                WebsiteContentId = contact.WebsiteContentId,
                OnlineSellerHomePageUrlContentId = contact.OnlineSellerHomePageUrlContentId,
                ContactFormUrlContentId = contact.ContactFormUrlContentId,
                RequestAQuoteUrlContentId = contact.RequestAQuoteUrlContentId,
                NameContentId = contact.NameContentId
            });
```

Removing the M:M relationships from the query produces a sane single query (albeit with many subselects).  As soon as a single M:M relationship is added to the projection, EF produces 2 queries with a UNION ALL for the results.

Here's our configuration as well:

```
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
            modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>()
                .HasMany(c => c.Brands)
                .WithMany(c => c.Contacts)
                .Map(mc =>
                {
                    mc.MapRightKey("BrandId");
                    mc.MapLeftKey("ContactId");
                    mc.ToTable("ContactBrands");
                });
            modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>()
                .HasMany(c => c.Categories)
                .WithMany(c => c.Contacts)
                .Map(mc =>
                {
                    mc.MapRightKey("CategoryId");
                    mc.MapLeftKey("ContactId");
                    mc.ToTable("ContactCategories");
                });
            modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>()
                .HasMany(c => c.ContactTypes)
                .WithMany(c => c.Contacts)
                .Map(mc =>
                {
                    mc.MapRightKey("ContactTypeId");
                    mc.MapLeftKey("ContactId");
                    mc.ToTable("ContactToContactType");
                });
        }
```

I am unsure of why EF is generating such a terrible query.  Any insight on how to possibly improve the query is immensely helpful.

Comment: Well, EF has to generate a monstrous SQL for your LINQ query. You should break it up and load all the related entities separately. Take a look at point 8.2.2 of performance troubleshooting doc: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh949853(v=vs.113).aspx#8%20Loading%20Related%20Entities

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity framework nested projections are slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42948326/entity-framework-nested-projections-are-slow)